# Mapping XFCE4/xRDP sessions to users

Tags: xfce, xrdp

I have Ubuntu 13.10 with Xubuntu Desktop - XFCE4.

I'm trying to use XDRP to allow MS Windows users to login to the machine with their own user.

I've been a lot around the houses with this! I've find two half-way solutions, but can't get them to work as I'd like...

1) in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` I set the `port` to -1

`[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1`

each time **any** user logs on they get a new session - they can never go back to their original session

2) in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` I set the `port` to 5912 (e.g)

`[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5912`

each time **any** user logs on they always log on to **the same session** irrespective of their logon details

??) I found a mid-way solution, to create a lot of sessions by adding adding additional options in the `xrdp.ini` e.g.

`[xrdp8]
name=Bob's Logon
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5913`

`[xrdp9]
name=Jill's Logon
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5914`

and so on, but he problem with this is that Jill can still log into Bob's remote session

???
Is it possible to to do what I'm trying to do?

Maybe I have to use different tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the user= field to the user in question, so if Jill's Logon is selected, it'll only ask for the password and sign in using the user provided in the file.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your issue, you could try to install the X11VNC package and configure xrdp to use this one.

You can find detailed instruction on this post (see see http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5439)

The guys is basically performing the following operations

1. Download the latest xrdp package from sourceforge
2. install some dependencies software so you can compile the xrdp packages
3. Compile the package
4. Install an alternate desktop (could be xfce or Desktop-MATE or LXDE) 
   5 Install X11VNC package
5. PErform some minor configuration changes so xrdp knows that it needs to use X11VNC
6. Configure the desktop to be used by the user while performing xrdp session
7. Reboot your machine
8. you should try and you should be good.

This setup will ensure that the user will always reconnect to its one session.

Remark:  In the mentioned post, the guy is compiling xrdp software.  We are assuming that you could probably use the ubuntu package, install the X11VNC package, perform the minor configuration changes and it should work as well

Let's us know if this worked for you....Share your findings......

See you